# How can i use cronjobs to run a python script every 2 hours?

Tags: python, cron

I have following python file that i want to execute every 2hours

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time



PATH = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)



driver.get("http://bitcoin.works")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_link_text('LOGIN').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_id("login_form_btc_address").send_keys("MyEmail")
driver.find_element_by_id("login_form_password").send_keys("securePassword")
driver.find_element_by_id("login_button").click()
time.sleep(4)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("pushpad_deny_button").click()
time.sleep(7)
driver.find_element_by_id("free_play_form_button").click()
time.sleep(3)

driver.quit()
```

This file runs in a virtualenv called scrape

so I first do

```
cd Documents/scrapping and than i activate the virtualenv like this
source scrape/bin/activate
```

and than I run the python file with

```
python run.py
```

Now to run this as a cronjob i did following:

I created a file called run.sh which has following content

```
#!/bin/sh
python run.py
```

i made the run.sh file executable with

```
chmod a+x run.sh
```

than i edited the cronjob file using crontab -e
and added this line

```
0 */2 * * *  cd Documents/scrapping && /bin/bash/ run.sh
```

Now when I change into the directory

```
`Documents/scrapping/
```

and run 
`./run.sh` with the virtualenvironment beeing activated

the script works and is beeing executed without any error

However the script doesnt run every 2 hours as its supposed to

How can I fix this?

Comment: Cron generally writes it's output to `/var/log/cron` file. Are you seeing any error there? Also, try changing the Cron expression to  `2 * * * *` to make it run every 2 minutes so that you can see what is the error if any.

Comment: Do you mean that it worked fine for the first time when you use the corn job, but does not get fired every two hours. I would do this `* */2 * * * python /yourpath/run.py > /dev/null 2>&1`, to get the logs, to see what i happening.

Comment: @AjayKrChoudhary I dont even have a cron directory in var/log

Comment: Edit run.sh and put in this line near the top: `export DISPLAY=:0`.

Comment: @charliebrown If you have not configured anything and everything is set to default. Then cron log goes to `/var/log/syslog`. Please check here with the help of the grep command.

Comment: @Roadowl May 10 00:06:44 ether anacron[6935]: Job `cron.daily' terminated
May 10 00:06:44 ether anacron[6935]: Normal exit (1 job run)